# Finding the range of equation. Any tricks?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, systems-of-equations

I m working on the following problem

For real numbers $a,b$, if $a+ab+b=3$, then find the range of $m=a-ab+b$. Is there any inequalities here to use?

Comment: So no restrictions on $a,b$, just reals, not even positive, right?

Comment: That is correct. Well, the only restriction is $a+ab+b=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $s=a+b$ and $t=a-b$. This is a lossless change of variables, so transform the condition:
\begin{align*}
3&=a+b+ab\\
12&=4s+(s+t)(s-t)\\
t^2&=s^2+4s-12=(s+6)(s-2)
\end{align*}
Therefore the condition can be satisfied only when the right side isn't negative, i.e. $s\notin(-6,2)$.

You want to find the range of $a+b-ab=a+b-(3-a-b)=2s-3$, but that's clearly $\mathbb R\setminus (-15,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you can get a more elementary answer, but you could see $1+a, 1+b$ are roots of $x^2-sx+4=0$, where $s^2\ge 16$. So, we have $m=(a+ab+b)-2(1+a)(1+b)+2(1+a+1+b)-2=2s-7\not \in (-15, 1)$.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the same way I found after I posted. Great ! If this was my homework question. I probably tried Lagrange multiplier lol

Answer (score 1):

You are given $a+ab+b=3$, which you can make $(a+1)(b+1)=4$.  Let $x=a+1, y=b+1$, so $xy=4$    $m=a-ab+b=x-1-(x-1)(y-1)+y-1=-xy+2x+2y-3=2x+2y-7=2x+\frac 8x-7$
Can you find the range of that?

Comment: Well, I can, but this question is for someone who is in 8th grade. He just learned parabola,linear and basic trigs. So he wouldn't be able to do that within his reach. I m looking for a more elementary way to solve this.

Comment: We explicitly encourage posting answers to your own questions if the answers you get lead you to one, but do not say it the way you want.  You can post your answer, then (after some time delay, I don't know how much) accept it.